# Rails: How can I regenerate all the views created by scaffold after I make changes to the underlying table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

New to Rails, so please feel free to edit my question should I get the terminology wrong!

I've created my MVC via scaffold, but have since made changes to the underlying table  (renamed some columns, added some columns).  Is there a way to regenerate the views that were created with the original scaffold such that they reflect the changes I've made?

If I run `rails g scaffold Foo --migration=false --skip` I get an error that my model name is already used in my application.

If delete the entire corresponding views folder (the one created by the original scaffold), and I run `rails g scaffold Foo --migration=false --force` the views generated still don't pick up all the fields I have in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse the scaffold generation and regenerate a new scaffold with renamed and new columns.

If you already migrated the database you will need to roll it back.

```
rake db:rollback
```

Then you can reverse the scaffold generation.

```
rails destroy scaffold MyFoo
```

Then generate new scaffold with updated columns

```
rails generate scaffold MyFoo column_name_1:data_type column_name_2:data_type column_name_3:data_type
```

Otherwise you can manually rewrite your views and controllers to include the updated and new columns.